# How to integrate GitLab code into SAP DataServices job?

Tags: git, gitlab, sap-data-services

I just had SAP DS jobs that use some python code from outside (now it's lying in network folder). I need to switch code source to GitLab. Does anybody now proper way to do it? Or any suggestions:)

I looked through the forums but didn't find any information about DS and GitLab collaboration.